# Universal database GUI

Tags: database, user-interface

i need one GUI that will work on windows and i need to connect on several databases. Access, mySQL, MSSQL, Postgres, SQLite and maybe in future i will need connection to oracle.

It would be nice that tool can move database schemas from one db engine to others without lot user interference...

Can someone recomend me tool for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can also look at http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/anysql/

Comment: More: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [navicat](http://www.navicat.com/). It should do everithing you need...

Answer (score 3):

Try on of these:

- [SQL Workbench/j](http://www.sql-workbench.net)
- [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com)

Both work on Windows, Linux and Mac.